# Summarize database values of the last 12 hours for each hour

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with the columns id, type, value, created_at and I want to sum up the last 12 hours with one query. The result should be in an array for each hour ago.

At the moment I use this query to fetch the data for an hour:

```
select sum(`value`) as aggregate from `clan_values` where `type` = '2' and `created_at` between '2016-04-12 10:00:00' and '2016-04-12 10:59:59'
```

I dont have any clue how to solve this with just one query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using this query, it'll return sum(value) for last 12 hours including the hour of current_timestamp().  If there are no rows for a certain hour you'll get a zero for the aggregate of that hour.

```
SELECT sum(IFNULL(`value`,0)) as aggregate,
       MyTime.MyHour,
       DATE_ADD(DATE(created_at),
                  INTERVAL HOUR(created_at) hour) as ActualHour
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
                  INTERVAL HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())-hour.count hour) as MyHour
  FROM
  (SELECT 0 as count
  UNION SELECT 1
  UNION SELECT 2
  UNION SELECT 3
  UNION SELECT 4
  UNION SELECT 5
  UNION SELECT 6
  UNION SELECT 7
  UNION SELECT 8
  UNION SELECT 9
  UNION SELECT 10
  UNION SELECT 11)AS Hour
   )as MyTime LEFT JOIN
   `clan_values` ON DATE_ADD(DATE(created_at),INTERVAL HOUR(created_at) hour) = MyTime.MyHour
AND `type` = '2'
GROUP BY MyTime.MyHour,ActualHour
ORDER BY MyTime.MyHour ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f5ec6/16)

Answer (score 1):

You can try group by DATE_FORMAT %H

```
select sum(`value`) as aggregate 
from `clan_values` 
where `type` = '2' and `created_at` between '2016-04-12 10:00:00' and '2016-04-12 10:59:59'
group by DATE_FORMAT( `created_at`,'%H');
```